# Convert numbers to HH:MM in R

Tags: r, dataframe, datetime, time

I'm working with a dataset with a time column in the following format:

```
Time 
330 
2230 
5 
45
```

I want to convert this to hh:mm format

```
Time 
03:30 
22:30 
00:05 
00:45
```

I'm new to R and I'm wondering if there's an easy way to do this.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pad the time strings to 4-digit with `"0"` on the left, then split the padded strings into `HH:MM`.

```r
df <- data.frame(Time = c(330, 2230, 5, 45))
```

###### Solution 1

```r
df$Time2 <- sub("(.{2})(.+)", "\\1:\\2", sprintf("%04d", df$Time))
```

###### Solution 2

```r
df$Time2 <- format(strptime(sprintf("%04d", df$Time), "%H%M"), "%H:%M")
```

###### Output

```
df
#   Time Time2
# 1  330 03:30
# 2 2230 22:30
# 3    5 00:05
# 4   45 00:45
```